# How can I check in latex whether a new chapter starts on current page?

Tags: latex, conditional-statements, tex

I am using the [everypage](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/everypage?lang=de) package. Using the \AddEverypageHook command I can repeat actions at the beginning of every page of a document. Now I want to do something like this:

```
\AddEverypageHook{
  \if "New chapter starts at current page." - "Do stuff." 
  \else "Do other stuff."
  \fi
}
```

How can I check in latex, whether a  new chapter starts at the current page?

Comment: It may just be easier to tap into the `\chapter` macro rather than check at every page. What is it that you want to do exactly?

Comment: Hi Werner. I added a colored thumb index to every page (this is the reason for the everypage package). This works quite well. However I want its appearance to be different for pages, that contain the "chapter X" string.

Comment: @ Werner: Since I do not know, whether any other code redefines the chapter macro somewhere, is it dangerous to do it again?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In a typical document, the issue of a `\chapter` command is followed by an automated page break. For example, see what `\chapter` does in [`report.cls`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/unpacked/report.cls):

```
\newcommand\chapter{\if@openright\cleardoublepage\else\clearpage\fi
                    \thispagestyle{plain}%
                    \global\@topnum\z@
                    \@afterindentfalse
                    \secdef\@chapter\@schapter}
```

It issues a `\clearpage` (or `\cleardoublepage`), flushing whatever is pending and starting on a new page.

So, depending on your setup, it may suffice to use the [`afterpage` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/afterpage)'s `\afterpage{<stuff>}` macro to execute `<stuff>` *after* the current page. For example, in your preamble, you would

```
\let\oldchapter\chapter % Store \chapter
\renewcommand{\chapter}{% Redefine \chapter to...
  \afterpage{\customcommand}% ...execute \customcommand after this page
  \oldchapter}
```

Of course, this would only make sense if you don't execute anything else on non-chapter pages since the condition is tied to `\chapter`. So, making a document-wide decision at *every* page might require a slightly different approach.

I'd still suggest tapping into the `\chapter` macro, but using a conditional. Here is an example (click to enlarge image):

[image]

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{lipsum,afterpage,everypage}

\newcounter{chapterpage}% For this example, a chapterpage counter
\newcounter{regularpage}% For this example, a regularpage counter
\newif\ifchapterpage% Conditional used for a \chapter page
% Just for this example, print page number using:
\renewcommand{\thepage}{\LARGE\thechapterpage--\theregularpage}

\AddEverypageHook{
  \ifchapterpage % If on a \chapter page...
    \stepcounter{chapterpage}% Increase chapterpage counter
    \global\chapterpagefalse% Remove conditional
  \else % ...otherwise
    \stepcounter{regularpage}% Increase regularpage counter
  \fi
}
\let\oldchapter\chapter % Store \chapter
\renewcommand{\chapter}{% Redefine \chapter to...
  \afterpage{\global\chapterpagetrue}% ... set \ifchapterpage to TRUE _after_ this page
  \oldchapter}

\begin{document}

\chapter{First chapter}\lipsum[1-50]
\chapter{Second chapter}\lipsum[1-50]
\chapter*{Third chapter}\lipsum[1-50]
\chapter{Final chapter}\lipsum[1-50]

\end{document}
```

The advantage of the above method is that it works for both `\chapter` and `\chapter*`. `\chapter*` doesn't increment the `chapter` counter and it is therefore insufficient to rely on a condition based on such a comparison.

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution. The idea is to check, whether the chapternumber counter has changed. This is done by a custom counter:

```
\newcounter{CurrentChapNum}
```

- if the chapter-counter did not change, we are still in the current chapter, so do \customcommand1 stuff.
- if the counter has changed, we seem to be at the beginning of a new chapter, so do \customcommand2 stuff and reset the CurrentChapNum-counter to the value of the current chapter.

This is done by this code.

```
\AddEverypageHook{ 
   \ifnum\value{chapter}=\value{CurrentChapNum} \customcommand1 
   \else \customcommand2 \setcounter{CurrentChapNum}{\value{chapter}} 
   \fi  
}
```

Since I am quite new to latex-markup-stuff I hope this is not too clumsy.

Comment: This usage should be fine, unless you're using `\chapter*`. I've added [an answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29733183/914686) addressing this.